# How would i go about coding this im very new and have no clue how to start this

Tags: python

You are a medical researcher running a study on a new drug. You are screening potential participants and you need to make sure you don't get any outliers. In particular, you want to flag anyone who is too tall/short or light/heavy. You need people who are in the "middle" so to speak to. Therefore, write a simple program to determine if a potential participant is eligible based on.

Weight
Height
Sex
Requirements

Collect these three data points through input() boxes
Determine a set of thresholds that indicate whether the patient is an outlier. You can determine any thresholds. For example, men must be between 5.2 feet and 6.8 feet tall and between 150 and 280 lbs.
Create flow logic to determine whether an inputted patient is within the thresholds
If they are an outlier, print a message indicating they are not eligible and tell them which thresholds they did not meet
Create as many 
In order to analyze data, we need to develop standard formats. For example, sex could be entered into a textbox as "female", "f", "Female", 0, 1, "Male", "Man", "woman", or it could be mispelled. Create an if/elif/else statement to handle as many possibilities as you can think of and then convert it to a standard format (e.g. f/m, female/male, 0/1). In other words make sure that it is always stored as one of two or three options (including "unknown" or empty).

For weight and height, determine a standard format as well. In addition, we need to correct errors before they are stored to maintain high quality data. For example, if you ask for height in inches, someone may make a typo and enter an extra digit. Use an if/elif/else statement to detect potential errors in height and weight. Prompt the user to correct those types of errors and any others you can think of.

Finally, some people are outliers and are overly tall/short, light/heavy. We don't want to make any decisions yet regarding how to address those outliers. However, we should flag anyone as a potential outlier. You should determine what the criterion is for being an outlier and apply it in an if/elif/else statement to flag someone.

Comment: Please don't just paste your entire exercise, instead give a small example where we can help you with

Answer (score 1):

This is very open ended, and as ToTheMax said, it would be better to give specific examples.  But since you have no clue how to start, I'm going to put in a few snippets to help get you on the right track.  See if you can run with that, and ask follow ups based on that.

Here is a simple command line input.  Just run this from your console with python script_name.py

```
print('Please type input and hit enter')
input1 = input() 
print(input1)
```

That should help get you going on the inputs.  The next part asks you to test the input, which means a series of if/elif/else statements.  Here is an example.

```
if input1 == 'male':
    print('this is a male')
elif input1 == 'female':
    print('female')
else:
    print('Not male or female')
```

Try working from these and reach out if you get stuck on something.

Comment: If this helps, please consider marking it as the Accepted Answer.  Thanks!